# How to run Jekyll on a virtual box server?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, jekyll

I'm on a Windows 7 x64 machine with Virtual Box and Vagrant installed. I installed

- Ruby
- Rubygems

correctly and installed jekyll. The final message I received on my PuTTY terminal is :

```
Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

When I visit the url on Windows Chrome browser, it says

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

What are the extra configurations that needs to be done so that Jekyll can run on the virtual box server?

Answer (score 4):

To access the jekyll instance in the virtual box server, run Jekyll with the server IP.

```
Usage:

  jekyll serve [options]

Options:

   -H, --host [HOST]  Host to bind to
```

Supposing the virtual server IP is `192.168.1.100` then run the following command in the server to make the jekyll instance accesible from outside:

```
jekyll serve -H 192.168.1.100
```

Then it will be accessible at http://192.168.1.100:4000

Comment: this help me but i had to check my vagrantfile for the private_network ip ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you dont use a static IP as mentioned in the other OP, you need to forward the port where jekyll will run

In your Vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.network :public_network
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4000, host: 4000,
```

You will start jekyll using the command

```
jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Then you could access your site from `http://localhost:4000/` from your host machine